# Why CSS property justify-content when set to center doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: css

I have encountered a problem. CSS property justify-content, when set to "center", doesn't seem to respond inside Firefox and inside JSFiddle. But when run in Chrome and new Edge it works fine. Why is this happening?
This is Firefox and JSFiddle: 
[image: Firefox example]
This is Chrome and Edge:
[image: Chrome example]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Firefox version  73.0.1
Chrome version 80.0.3987.122
Edge version 80.0.361.62

Comment: Where is your HTML? you can edit your question to add a code snippet use the icon with `<>`

Comment: Set `height` to `body`.

Comment: @MonteCristo One `div` inside `body` do you really need HTML?

Comment: In Firefox the `<body>` probably grows to the height of the inner div and not anymore, unlike in Chrome or Safari. If you set `body { min-height: 100vh; }` that should fix the issue.

Comment: @Kosh Yes, this fix it. But my question is why this happens? Can you answer that?

Comment: @Terry Thank you, Terry, this was helpful.

Comment: `body` has different default values of `height` in FF and Chrome (Edge).

Comment: @Terry Can you write your answer?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic Sure thing, give me a sec

Comment: your code doesn't reproduce the issue. I am pretty sure you either have more CSS involved or a cache issue. I invite you to test the snippet I created in all the browsers and you will see the same output

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it again but there is still a difference. There is no more CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif But i now see that my Firefox is 74.0 not 73. Do you have same versions of browser as i am?

Comment: windows or Linux based?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

---

It happened because you didn't write `height` and `width` for `body`
in some case it cause problem in firefox in some case in chrome.

I always do this to prevent all problems

I want to tell you : you most said that  `align-items : center` vertical's centering is not working

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: I didn't ask how to get same output. I asked why this happens.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic so why did you accept the other answer that is not explaining why it's happening and giving you a way to have the same output? like this one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah i see that now. I removed acceptance.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic  for vertical centering it  align-items: center
for  horizontal its   justify-content: center;

Comment: @TemaniAfif Don't understand why you are being so vindictive. If you have a problem with my answer, leave a comment there instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from the fact that your `<body>` element is not growing to the full height of the viewport. It fact, it simply expands to the height of the inner `<div>`, thereby making it look like it is not vertically centering the element.

If you add a minimum height to the `<body>` element to 100vh, that should fix the issue. This forces the `<body>` element to be *at least* as tall as the viewport.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't explain the difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not sure what do you mean by "does not explain"??

Comment: The OP is having two different results in two browsers and asking why. By the way, I am not able to reproduce both behavior. The same happen in all the browsers for me

Comment: html , will be 100% height of viewport (it can't be smaller), body is only suppose to grow with its content. If chrome/edge thinks it should be also be min-height: the viewport; it is not the case for FF or older version of chrome and MS browsers.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your answer (and I already added a comment). The OP is asking a question and I am intrested to know  why he have such behavior and why it's happening but if at the end the OP himself doesn't want to know then he should change the question and make it : *how to make all the browser behave the same* and in this case we have two answers for this. by the way, I never said your answer is wrong or invalid I said *it doesn't explain the difference the OP is having*